# Wireless driver not loading after changing ownership of /usr/lib. How can I restore default ownership?

Tags: 12.04, permissions, chown

I have changed the ownership of /usr/lib by mistake as root:root by running the below command:

```
sudo chown -R root:root /usr/lib/
```

Now, the wireless drivers are not loading and also I am not able to shutdown or restart the system without using the terminal. I changed back some of the folders' ownership to the username and temporarily solved few problems.

Do I need to format my system? If anyone has a better solution, please help!

Comment: Looks like most of /usr/lib should be root:root so you might get away by manually altering files. If you got doubts about specific files please include the names and someone  will be able to tell you what their settings are ;)

Comment: I have already changed /usr/lib/apache2 properties.. everything else that i am aware of is working fine . But the wifi drivers are not loading. also I am not able to shutdown or restart the system without using the termina

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to ubuntu (installed it on a flash drive today) but I think the best option is try to back up your data (the live DVD or USB may be helpful) and then perform a format and re-install your ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, based on my machine's /usr/lib permissions (Ubuntu 13.04):

```
sudo chgrp utempter /usr/lib/utempter
sudo chgrp messagebus /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
sudo chgrp mail /usr/lib/evolution/camel-lock-helper-1.2
sudo chgrp utmp /usr/lib/libvte-2.90-9/gnome-pty-helper
sudo chgrp utmp /usr/lib/utempter/utempter
```